# Calculating number of page table entries given bits of virtual & physical memory addresses & each virtual page?

Tags: virtual-memory, page-tables

Is there any sort of formula to calculate the number of page table entries if I am given:

- number of bits in address of virutal memory
- number of bits in address of physical memory
- size of each virtual page in KB

I think it is 2^some number but is there a formula to find that 'some number'?

Comment: What do you know about converting a virtual address to its corresponding physical address?

Comment: Not too sure, I know that a virtual address can be partitioned into 2 parts, virtual page no and page offset and physical address into physcial page no and page offset. And then look the physical page number at PageTable[virtual page number]? That's the only thing I know but I'm unsure how to apply that here

Comment: Can you determine how many bits are used for the virtual page number?  If so, that will tell you how many different virtual pages there can be.